# Fetch data from map Marker using datasnapshot

Tags: android, firebase, google-maps, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

I have this db:

```
{
  "Locale" : {
    "Feed1" : {
      "title" : "title1"
      "desc" : "description"
       "lat" : 47.56494,
      "lng" : 46.245,
    },
    "Feed2" : {
      "desc" : "Desc nomer 2",
      "id" : "id 2",
      "lat" : 45.56494,
      "lng" : 47.245,
      "title" : "title2"
    }
  },
}
```

I have added g-map on my activity with markers. When I click on marker it's open new detail activity. So I want this marker to pass data from marker into detail activity.

I use onMarkerClick:

```
override fun onMarkerClick(marker: Marker): Boolean {
        mRefLocal.addValueEventListener(vael)
        return false
    }
```

it is my addValueEventListener(vael)

```
  var vael: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
            override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
                for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
                    val feeds = snapshot.getValue(Feeds::class.java)
                    title = feeds!!.title
                    id = feeds.id
                    desc = feeds.desc
                }
                val intent = Intent(this@MapsActivity, FeedsDetail::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("id", id)
                intent.putExtra("desc", desc)
                intent.putExtra("title", title)
                startActivity(intent)
                Toast.makeText(this@MapsActivity, title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
            override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
        }
```

So no matter what marker I click I always get the same data from db.
I want to get assigned data from the clicked marker. What's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using the following code:

```
override fun onMarkerClick(marker: Marker): Boolean {
    mRefLocal.addValueEventListener(vael)
    return false
}
```

You are adding a listener on the `mRefLocal` node, which points to the `Locale` node, and not to a particular `FeedsDetail` object. The `Locale` node contains all `FeedsDetail` objects. So instead of that, you should use:

```
mRefLocal.child(marker.title).addValueEventListener(vael)
```

See, I have added a call to `.child(marker.name)`. Since you don't have a `name` property, you should add it under each object. Your schema should look like this:

```
{
  "Locale" : {
    "Feed1" : {
       "name" : "Feed1", //Added
       "title" : "title1",
       "desc" : "description1",
       "id" : "id 1",
       "lat" : 47.56494,
       "lng" : 46.245
    },
    "Feed2" : {
       "name" : "Feed2", //Added
       "title" : "title2",
       "desc" : "Desc nomer 2",
       "id" : "id 2",
       "lat" : 45.56494,
       "lng" : 47.245
    }
  },
}
```

See, the new `name` property under each object?

> So no matter what marker I click I always get the same data from db.

Let me guess, it's always the last one, right? Please note, that this is the expected behavior since you are looping through all objects and you are adding to the `Intent` only last one. So you assign to the `title`, `id` and `desc` variables, values only from the last iteration.

> I want to get assigned data from the clicked marker.

To get the data only of a particular element, please use the following code:

```
var vael: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
        val feeds = dataSnapshot.getValue(Feeds::class.java)

        val intent = Intent(this@MapsActivity, FeedsDetail::class.java)
        intent.putExtra("id", feeds.id)
        intent.putExtra("desc", feeds.desc)
        intent.putExtra("title", feeds!!.title)
        startActivity(intent)
        Toast.makeText(this@MapsActivity, title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    }
    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
}
```

See, now there is no need for any loop since the listener is added only on a particular `FeedsDetail` object.

> So I want this marker to pass data from marker into detail activity.

Using this solution, you are only passing the details of the marker that is clicked.

Comment: hi, when I add this      mRefLocal.child(marker.name).addValueEventListener(vael),   where should I add the name, because it is red(error).

Comment: First, add a new **`name`** field in your `FeedsDetail` class and second, add it also in the database as explained in the above schema. Does it work now?

Comment: name field in FeedsDetail you mean var name: String? = null?, I did what you said and it is still red

Comment: The name should first be added in your `FeedsDetail` class, in the database and inside the `Marker` object. So every `Marker` object should set the `Title` with the corresponding name. For instance, if a location has a marker that has the name `Feed1`, then you should set the title as `Feed1`. To get then the name of the marker, you should use `maker.title`, as in my updated answer. Sorry for wrting `marker.name`, my bad.

Comment: I put title inside  mRefLocal.child(marker.title).addValueEventListener(vael), now it works, thank you, you really helped me!

Answer (score 1):

Load your markers from firebase in onMapReady.

```
override fun onMapReady(googleMap: GoogleMap) {
    mMap = googleMap
    mRefLocal.addValueEventListener(vael)
}
```

when you create your marker set your feed object

```
var vael: ValueEventListener = object : ValueEventListener {
    override fun onDataChange(dataSnapshot: DataSnapshot) {
         for (snapshot in dataSnapshot.children) {
            val feeds = snapshot.getValue(Feeds::class.java)
            val marker = mMap.addMarker(MarkerOptions())
            marker.tag = feeds
        }
    }
    override fun onCancelled(databaseError: DatabaseError) {}
}
```

Open in your activity - onClickMarker

```
override fun onMarkerClick(marker: Marker): Boolean {
    val feed = marker.tag as Feed
    val intent = Intent(this@MapsActivity, FeedsDetail::class.java)
    intent.putExtra("id", feed.id)
    intent.putExtra("desc", feed.desc)
    intent.putExtra("title", feed.title)
    startActivity(intent)
    Toast.makeText(this@MapsActivity, title, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    return false
}
```

Comment: you need to execute onMapReady